# How to extract time interval data from minute data in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract rows at 5 minute intervals from 1 minute data. My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1509408000, 1509408000, 1509408000, 
1509408000, 1509408000, 1509408000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(-2209021500, -2209021560, 
-2209021620, -2209021680, -2209021740, -2209021800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), O = c(3674, 3675, 3674, 3675, 3675, 
3675), H = c(3674, 3675, 3675, 3676, 3676, 3675), L = c(3673, 
3674, 3674, 3674, 3675, 3675), C = c(3673, 3674, 3674, 3675, 
3675, 3675)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

structure(list(Date = structure(c(1506902400, 1506902400, 1506902400, 
1506902400, 1506902400, 1506902400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(-2209071300, -2209071360, 
-2209071420, -2209071480, -2209071540, -2209071600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), O = c(3450, 3451, 3451, 3452, 3450, 
3449), H = c(3451, 3451, 3451, 3452, 3452, 3451), L = c(3448, 
3449, 3449, 3450, 3450, 3449), C = c(3448, 3451, 3450, 3451, 
3452, 3450)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have looked at:

[Create a time interval of 15 minutes from minutely data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827572/create-a-time-interval-of-15-minutes-from-minutely-data-in-r)

[How to subset and extract time series by time interval in row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903994/how-to-subset-and-extract-time-series-by-time-interval-in-row)

but none do exactly what I want. Maybe I could use this:
   `substr(t,15,16)=="00"`.

but I'm not sure how to combine it with `filter`.

Desired Output: find rows at 30 minute intervals:

[image: Desired Output: find rows at 30 minute intervals:]

Comment: Could you add more data to your example ?

Comment: So you want rows whose `Time` value is at a 5-minute mark?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide a desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select every nth row from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279550/select-every-nth-row-from-dataframe) as you know that every row is separated by 1mn

Comment: I haven't used looking at every nth row as some data is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract rows with a minute-mark ending in 0 or 5 with

```
df[substr(format(df$Time, '%M'), 2, 2) %in% c(0, 5),]
# or 
df[as.numeric(format(df$Time, '%M')) %% 5 == 0,]
# or 
df[grep('[0|5]$', format(df$Time, '%M')),]
```

With `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(substr(format(df$Time, '%M'), 2, 2) %in% c(0, 5))

# or 

df %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(format(df$Time, '%M')) %% 5 == 0)
```

Comment: will the filter example pick up minute-mark ending in 0 or 5?

Comment: Yes, it just checks if the minute is an integer multiple of `5`, i.e. the minute-mark divided by 5 has a remainder of 0. I added the substr option to filter too, but they give the same result.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the code and it works. I was also looking for help to create the intervals if there are missing rows at the beginning i.e. if 14:30 is not there starting from 14:29

Comment: You'll have to add more to your question descibing what you want to be done in those cases, because it's not 100% clear. Select the next one? The previous one? What if there are >1 missing? What if a single row is the closest non-missing Time-value to two different 5-minute makrs, should it be used twice? et cetera.